# Remove subsequent elements with the same substring

Tags: r

I have an n by 2 object containing variable names in the 1st column and numeric values (scores) in the 2nd column:

```
 data      <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 20, ncol = 2))
 data[, 2] <- 1:20
 data[, 1] <- c("example_a_1", "example_a_2", "example_a_3",
                "example_b_1", "example_c_1", "example_d_1",
                "example_d_2", "example_d_3", "example_f_1",
                "example_g_1", "example_g_2", "example_h_1",
                "example_i_1", "example_l_1", "example_o_1",
                "example_j_1", "example_m_1", "example_p_1",
                "example_k_1", "example_n_1")
data
            X1 X2
1  example_a_1  1
2  example_a_2  2
3  example_a_3  3
4  example_b_1  4
5  example_c_1  5
6  example_d_1  6
7  example_d_2  7
8  example_d_3  8
9  example_f_1  9
10 example_g_1 10
11 example_g_2 11
12 example_h_1 12
13 example_i_1 13
14 example_l_1 14
15 example_o_1 15
16 example_j_1 16
17 example_m_1 17
18 example_p_1 18
19 example_k_1 19
20 example_n_1 20
```

I don't want this object to contain similar variables -- if a variable name has the same first 9 characters (in this example) as another, then it's repetitious. In those cases I only want to keep the first of the similarly named variables.

I can get a list of which variable names are repetitious like this:

```
 rep <- as.data.frame(table(substr(data[,1], 1, 9)))
 rep <- rep[rep[, 2] > 1, ]
 rep
       Var1 Freq
1 example_a    3
4 example_d    3
6 example_g    2
```

and thus identify them in a `for` loop or other conditional:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(substr(data[i, 1], 1, 9) %in% rep[,1])){
    # What goes here?
    #   or what's another approach?
  }
}
```

However, I'm not sure what logic I can use to remove the rows with repetitious names?

The final object should look like this:

```
data
           X1 X2
1 example_a_1  1
2 example_b_1  4
3 example_c_1  5
4 example_d_1  6
5 example_f_1  9
6 example_g_1 10
7 example_h_1 12
8 example_i_1 13
9 example_l_1 14
10 example_o_1 15
11 example_j_1 16
12 example_m_1 17
13 example_p_1 18
14 example_k_1 19
15 example_n_1 20
```

Comment: `data[!duplicated(substr(data$X1, 1, 9)), ]`?

Comment: I prefer @RobertH 's solution using duplicated, feel free to change your accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `duplicated`

```
short <- substr(data[,1], 1, 9)
i <- duplicated(short)
data <- data[!i , ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
data  <- data %>% 
            group_by(my9=substr(X1,1,9)) %>% 
            filter(row_number(my9)==1) %>% 
            select(-my9)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a column with the shortened name and aggregate on that column:

```
data$short <- substr(data[,1], 1, 9)
agg <- aggregate(data$X2~data$short, FUN=min)
```

I used min because you seem to be interested in the smallest score for each repetitive name

Comment: That's a good approach too. +1 Though the scores were totally arbitrary in this example, though in my actual use case I could do this and replace `min` with `max`.